# Solving a third degree polynomial without calculator

Tags: polynomials

I was just wondering if it is possible to find a solution to this without using a CAS/Calculator (with wolframalpha I get $x \approx 3.865$)

$\dfrac{1}{x^3} = \dfrac{4}{(10-x)^{3}}, x\in\mathbb{R}$

Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

*Hint:*
$$
\dfrac{1}{x^3} = \dfrac{4}{(10-x)^{3}}
\iff
\left(\dfrac{10-x}{x}\right)^3 = 4
\iff
\left(\dfrac{10}{x}-1\right)^3 = 4
$$

*Solution:*

> $x= \dfrac{10}{\sqrt[3]{4}+1} \approx 3.864882$

Comment: And assuming you proceed by taking real cube roots, the remaining two (complex) solutions are obtained by using $\sqrt[3]{4}(-\frac12\pm\frac12i\sqrt{3})$ as the roots on the right hand side. The factors in parentheses are the other cube roots of $1$.

Comment: Well, that was way easier than I thought... :D
Thank you for your nice answer!
And thank you MPW for this hint.

Answer (score 0):

$$ \frac{1}{x^3} = \frac{4}{(10-x)^3} \\
\left( \frac{10-x}{x} \right) ^3 = 4 \\
\frac{10-x}{x} = \sqrt[3]{4} \\
\frac{10}{x} = 1 + \sqrt[3]{4} \\
x = \frac{10}{1 + \sqrt[3]{4}}
$$